# How do I find more than one value close to another value?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I know that to retrieve the closest value to 0, I could use the following:

```
filter(abs(x-0)==min(abs(x-0)))
```

...with `x` being your vector. How do I retrieve the closest *two* values to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` version; you can use `top_n` to get the `n` smallest (or largest) values for some field:

```
df = data.frame(x = runif(100, -1, 1))

df %>%
  mutate(dist.from.0 = abs(x - 0)) %>%
  top_n(-2, dist.from.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tt <- sample(-200:200, 20)
tt[order(abs(tt), decreasing = F)][1:2]
```

Like that?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use `sort()`?

```r
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(10)
sort(abs(x-0))[1:2]
#> [1] 0.1836433 0.3053884
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

I also don't think the `-0` does anything for you so could just do `abs(x)`.

Comment: Thank to both of you! Both your solutions works - though I'd need to use it within `dplyr` because I will need the two closest values to 0 in each of my conditions. (sorry, that was not mentioned in the question).

Comment: @RobertP. - if you  modify your question to more accurately reflect your use case, you'll get more tailored answers. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for tips.